# Автоматизированное создание проекта в Visual Studio

Tags: ide, directx, c++, visual-studio

Здравствуйте.
Разбираюсь с DirectX в Visual Studio 2010. Возникла проблема: не получается автоматизировать создание проекта (plugin wizard работает, но проект какой-то нерабочий генерит). Проект `3dmax proj` появляется в окне `New project`. Я уже переписывал файлы и копировал их из howto. Ничего хорошего не вышло. Раньше вообще мастер и не вызывался, а когда заменил, в одном из файлов `07` на `10` (как я понял, версия моей студии), мастер стал вызываться. В чем проблема??? Как заставить мастера генерировать рабочие проекты?

Comment: Так мастера из разных студий несовместимы! Начинач от того, что изменяется сам интерфейс среды вплоть до того, что у разных версий компилятора и компоновщика разные ключи командной строки. Вообще для меня загадка - откуда Вы мастера взяли ? По умолчанию такого типа проектов в VS.NET нет. Возможно, необходимо поставить последнюю версию DirectX SDK.

Comment: По умолчанию-нет, вот и приходится корячиться....

Answer (score 3):

Вообще стандартом де-факто *(в случае, если не используются стороние билд-системы типа [**cmake**](http://www.cmake.org/))* в `Visual Studio` **стало создание проекта через вариант Empty Project.**

Руками кидаете исходный код в папки, добавляете их в проект, устанавливаете необходимые вам `Include Directories`, настраиваете библиотеки через `Linker - Additional Dependencies`, дописываете какие-либо `Prebuild` и `Postbuild events` - и готово.

Проще, понятнее, отсутствует нагроможденный стандартным wizard'ом `stdafx.h` *(ну вот зачем, объясните мне, пихать `precompiled header` во все проекты по дефолту да еще и обзывать его таким идиотским именем?*) и прочие автосгенерированные вещи.

Comment: Хм... Я не профессионал в этом деле и некоторые вещи не дополял(...
Для полного понимания можете построчно сказать что куда и для чего...
Не откажусь и от ссылки на полезный сайт... Вообще потерял надежду связать студию с 3d max(((

Comment: @Alerr Я сейчас понял, что совершенно не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. `Visual Studio` - среда для написания кода, `3ds max` - среда для создания `asset'ов`. Если у вас есть какой-либо игровой движок, то все эти `asset'ы` *(3д-модели, текстуры, шейдера и т.п)* создаются отдельно и подгружаются в движок **уже в рантайме.** Соответственно, вопрос - что именно вы хотите заинтегрировать в двух принципиально разных частях `development pipeline`?

Comment: Я это понимаю... Всё делается в 3d max, а лишь затем экспортируется в студию... Для начала я хочу заставить компилиться код созданный мастером... Затем экспортировать проекты в студию...